# Old Flutter code (1.5.4) with access to Map does not work in Flutter 2.8.1

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below works fine in Flutter 1.5.4, but does not want to in 2.8.1:

```
  void main() {
    String result;

    var questions = [
  {
    'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
    'answers': ['Blue', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', 'Snow-white']
  },
  {
    'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
    'answers': ['Hamster', 'Owl', 'Rabbit', 'Bear']
  },
];

    result = questions[0]['questionText'];
    print(result);
  }
```

To make it running, I have to force convertion to String :((

```
result = questions[0]['questionText'] as String;
```

Comment: Read about [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety). `Map.operator []` returns a nullable type so that it can return `null` on failure.

Comment: Thank you, you're right :) If I use List as Value in Map, then Dart requires to do explicity type conversion. If I use String as Value - then implicit conversion works :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use var keyword and flutter will think it's dynamic, that is why it will show error, as unkown type. If you make this below

```
Map<String, String> myMap = {'word': 'Show'};
```

There is no need for convertion to String.

Comment: Hello! I've got that. My real code is bit more complex, so I've edited my original question. What about that?

Comment: 1. `var` means that the type should be inferred.  It will be `dynamic` only if the inferred type is `dynamic` or if the type cannot be inferred. 2. This problem is unrelated to `dynamic` types anyway; it's really about null safety.

Comment: You can make it like List<Map<String, dynamic>>